# Inserting multiple values into the same column name + overwriting/update existing entries?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

This is a 2 part question which is pretty related, hence why I combined it into one:

**Part 1**

I have the arrays `$country` and `$redirect` each with up to 3 different values (a sum of six between them).

I however, only have two columns in my table, `country` and `redirect`. I would like to use an insert query that would insert `$country[0], $country[1], etc` into the column `country` and the same for `$redirect[0], $redirect[1], etc` with the column `redirect`.

This might be a stupid question, but would this INSERT query work, simply looping values to columns?

```
INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) values ('$country[0]', '$redirect[0]', '$country[1]', '$redirect[1]', '$country[2]', '$redirect[2]')
```

If not, how could I get this to work? I could use a `for` loop, but I'm concerned about the resource usage.

---

**Part 2**

How do I overwrite/update a row, where the value of column `country` already exists.

For example, `Great Britain` already exists within the column `country` with `http://en-gb` in the same row but within the column `redirect`.

I have an INSERT query such as `INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) VALUES ('Great Britain', 'http://uk')`, and I'd like to overwrite/update the row where `Great Britain` already exists within column `country` with the new `redirect` value.

Any answers/comments would be very, very, very much appreciated :)!!

Comment: Do you want your multiple values on new rows? And for the second part, what you want is to set `country` as a unique index and INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. This type of operation is sometimes refered to as UPSERT (although this is not a valid MySQL keyword).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To your first question, do it like this and it will work:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) 
VALUES ('$country[0]', '$redirect[0]'), 
       ('$country[1]', '$redirect[1]'), 
       ('$country[2]', '$redirect[2]')
```

To your second question: You need a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) on `country` and then can use [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) VALUES ('Great Britain', 'http://uk')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE redirect='http://uk';
```

Or with multiple values:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (country, redirect) 
VALUES ('$country[0]', '$redirect[0]'), 
       ('$country[1]', '$redirect[1]'), 
       ('$country[2]', '$redirect[2]')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE redirect=VALUES(redirect)
```

Comment: You can reference the value you intended to insert with the function `VALUES(...)`. I added an example for this.